# How to fix "apray not defined" error when running react with Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I have set up react using Docker but I am getting an error saying apray not defined

```
Dockerfile.dev 

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]


docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
  tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    command: ["npm", "run", "test"]
```